# Optional module dependencies in Port@l

Tags: java, portal

In [Port@l](http://code.google.com/p/isotrol-portal-m2/), all declared module dependencies seem to be mandatory. Is it 
possible to have optional dependencies in a module? If so, how are they
declared?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Port@l](http://code.google.com/p/isotrol-portal-m2/) modules are potentially incomplete [Spring Application Contexts](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/beans.html). Beans that are referenced from the application context but are not part of it must be declared as dependencies in the module interface and it will be considered as mandatory.

However, if you declare as a dependency in the module interface a bean that is alreay part of the application context, Port@l will consider it an optional dependency.